# How to Update the live tile with more than 5 items in Win 8 Metro style apps

Tags: windows-8

In my windows 8 metro style application I will get the records more than 5 from the database and I will put those records in an collection. So accordingly I need to update my first 5 records in the first iteration after completion of showing those first 5 items I need to display the next 5 items or remaining items which are already stored in the collection. I am doing this using C# and Xaml.

Please provide some piece of code or suggestions in doing this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSDN documentation is great for this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465429.aspx

Note that you can queue as many items as you like, but only the last 5 will actually cycle and show. If you are consistent with tagging your notifications, the tile will always show the 5 most recent.